# CakePHP question: How can i call a view of one controller from another controller?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

This is posts/index.php =>

```
<?php foreach ($allposts as $post) {
            echo '<tr class="class_row">';
            echo '<td>';

            echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
                                array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view',$post['Post']['id']),
                                array('id'=>'id_anchor_title','class'=>'class_anchor_title') );
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
}
?>
```

I want to call this posts/index.ctp from products/index.ctp => It will be a generic/common index.ctp for all controller. How can i do this ?

In posts/index.ctp the $allposts is used. It's set in posts/index action. But when i will call posts/index.ctp from products/index action different variable is set there. Suppose $this->set('allproducts',$allproducts); is set in products/index action. Now how can i use that allproducts variable in posts/index.ctp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vins stated, you can use `$this->render('view_name');` at the end of your controller action to render a different view (In your case it should be `$this->render('/posts/index');`)

In terms of using the variable you want, there are a couple things you can do. One would be to change your `set` function in each controller to use a common name. For example the posts controller could have `$this->set('results',$allposts);` and the products controller could have `$this->set('results',$allproducts);` Doing this, you can always reference `$results` in your view file. You might also want to set another variable, `$pageModel`. `$this->set('pageModel','Product');` in your products controller for example. Then your posts/index.php file could do something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($results as $result) {
            echo '<tr class="class_row">';
            echo '<td>';

            echo $this->Html->link($result[$pageModel]['title'],
                                array('controller'=>$this->controller,'action'=>'view',$result[$pageModel]['id']),
                                array('id'=>'id_anchor_title','class'=>'class_anchor_title') );
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>';
}
?>
```

notice that I replaced `'controller' => 'posts'` with `'controller' => $this->controller` This will make your view dynamic so the links will always point to the view action of the correct controller.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `$this->render('view_name');`  to use the another view for some other action. I'm not sure how exactly you're going to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to render posts/index.ctp instead of products/index.ctp, use `$this->render('/posts/index');`

Or you may want to put that in an element (that's the same idea of generic/common index.ctp).